# How to route to child links?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have my routing setup like below

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { Test1Component } from "./pages/test1/test1.component";
import { Test2Component } from "./pages/test2/test2.component";
import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
},{
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [{
        path: "test1",
        component: Test1Component,
        outlet: "contentarea"
    },{
        path: "test2",
        component: Test2Component,
        outlet: "contentarea"
    }]
}];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <a [routerLink]="['/home/test1']">Go to Test 1</a> <!-- Not working -->
        <router-outlet name="contentarea"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to route to `http://localhost:4200/home` and `http://localhost:4200/login`, however it fails when I try to navigate to `http://localhost:4200/test1`.

How to fix the link so that when I go to `http://localhost:4200/home/test1` it loads `test1` in `contentarea` ?

Comment: I guess this can be doable by `[routerLink]="['/home', { outlet: { contentarea: 'test1' } }]"`

Comment: @PankajParkar I did try that and it was working at some point but was creating ugly urls with round brackets

Comment: Because that is how `router-outlet` intended to work IMO. you can't mention them in route like segmented route..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `outlet: "..."` and `name="..."`

```ts
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
},{
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [{
        path: "test1",
        component: Test1Component,
    },{
        path: "test2",
        component: Test2Component,
    }]
}];
```

```ts
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <a [routerLink]="['/home/test1']">Go to Test 1</a> <!-- Not working -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

There always has to be exactly one unnamed router-outlet. Named outlets can only be in addition to the unnamed outlet and are named auxiliary routes or aux routes.

Comment: Wow I spent like 18 hours trying to fix this problem, did not know that it was  that easy, Thanks man

Comment: Most things are easy once you know how ;-) Glad to hear you could make it work .

Comment: "There always has to be exactly one unnamed router-outlet"... I thought that it was for the whole application

Comment: No, that's for each route segment, but now that you mention it, it's rather obvious that this can be misinterpreted.